# Ant fixCRLF target seems to alter other characters

Tags: ant, eol

I'm trying to create an Ant target to convert all line endings in a project to CRLF

```
<target name="eol-conversion">
    <echo message="Converting EOL" />
    <property name="workspace.root" location="../../.." />
    <property name="theproject" location="${workspace.root}/theproject" />
    <echo message="${theproject}" />
    <fixcrlf srcdir="${theproject}" includes="**/*.fileext" eol="crlf" />
</target>
```

It finds the target directory ok, but it changes all occurrences of (£) to (ï¿½) when I run the target.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong as I've basically just taken one of the examples from the Ant Apache manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind! I found that adding encoding="ISO-8859-1" into the fixcrlf tag fixed the issue.